# Short path if files is in the same directory

Tags: matlab

If dataset and Matlab script are both in the same folder, is it possible to denote to dataset in my script as `'../dataset.csv'`? I tried it in my script but it doesn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 0):

The two dots refer to the parent folder. Try `'./dataset.csv'` or even `'dataset.csv'`.